# Chapter name and chapter title

Tags: chapters

What is the difference between chapter name and chapter title? When I write

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

I assume 'Introduction' is the chapter title. Then, what's the chapter name in this case? I guess they are not the same thing, since there are commands `\ChNameVar` and `\ChTitleVar` in `fncychap` package.

Comment: Is the word 'Chapter' itself the chapter name?

Comment: Most chapter styles write something like (in English): Chapter 1 - Introduction, here chaptername is "Chapter" literally hold in `\chaptername`

Comment: I guess the package documentation wasn't helpful to you.

Comment: The macro \chaptername is very useful when changing languages.